# RewriteRule for profile system

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to redirect `website.com/member/gami` To `website.com/member.php?name=gami`

I have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/member$ member.php?name=$1 [NC, QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown rules, please try following htaccess rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Internal rewrite rules for non-existing uris to php files internally.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ $1.php?name=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: @Gami, Please do let me know what is sample url you are hitting? What error are you getting?

Comment: Changed the .htaccess file location and it started working. Thank you!

Comment: @Gami, Your welcome. You could mention in your question what was the previous path of htaccess. then you could edit my answer too by which location change it started working, that could be helpful for users, cheers.

Comment: I made a mistake with the file path because my hosting already had a .htaccess file somewhere else. First I placed the file in the correct place, but after it didn't work I started trying different paths and found my hosting's file

Comment: @Gami, sure, thanks for letting know, happy learning.

Comment: I also have a question about your answer. It works with the member file but I also tested it with a login.php file and it looks like it adds the parameter to the link. Why is that?

Comment: @Gami, ok try changing FROM `[QSA,L]` to `[L]` in last line of my htaccess and see if that helps? Clear cache before testing your URLs.